# Django models.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I created an App called **order** whose `models.py` (model name **create_order**) contain fields like **order_created_by, cloth_type, clothe colour, size, delivery_date, order_created_date**. Now in `models.py` of warehouse app, I want to see all the field of **created_order** model. How can I do that? And can do this all using first importing models in views.py of warehouse and the creating function then returning the `HttpResponse` using `models.objects.all()`. But I want to see these all fields of **create_order** in `admin.py` of warehouse app.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use [Django Model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance). For example, in your `orders/models.py` file you can create an Abstract model that will contain all the common fields. But to make your project clean and structured its a nice idea to create another app with the name of **core** or **utils** (most common name in the Django community) and put all common files there.

```py
class CommonFieldModel(models.Model):
    order_created_by = ...
    cloth_type = ...
    clothe = ...
    colour = ...
    size = ...
    delivery_date = ...
    order_created_date = ...

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

# order/models.py
class YourOrderAppModel(CommonFieldModel):
    # Will contain all CommonField Model fields + all other field you define here.
    ...

    
# warehouse/models.py
class YourWareHouseModel(CommonFieldModel):
    # this model will contain all  CommonField model fields
    # You can also define other fields here.
    ...
```

By default `abstract` is `False`.

Comment: thanks for the answer @Mubashar. I am trying to apply your concept and it gave me this error:-
OperationalError at /admin/wherehouse/wherehouse_model/
no such column: wherehouse_wherehouse_model.product_name
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/wherehouse/wherehouse_model/
Django Version: 3.1.6
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value: 
no such column: wherehouse_wherehouse_model.product_name
Exception Location: /Users/admin/.local/share/virtualenvs/test-IRChY3xp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py, line 413, in  execute

Comment: please help me in fixing this problem.

Comment: Make sure you migrate the database. You can use `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate`